# I get an error when running amplify publish or push

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, publish, aws-amplify

I set up another dev environment on my amplify project pushed it to the project and then removed it when I was done.

I then started working on the main project again and when I wanted to push the changes I got this error:

`You have already connected branches to your Amplify Console app. Please visit the Amplify Console to manage your branches.`

I have no idea how to get any of my changes up to amplify now... This blocks both publish and push and I can't see what they mean by "manage your branches" as there is only my main branch now on the amplify console.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a branch connected to amplify.
Solution: go to Amplify and enter in the app. General Settings -> edit and switch off Branch autodetection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't even remember which project I had this error on anymore, it was almost a year ago, but I must have solved it by now...

I'll leave this Question and Answer up in case someone else has the same problem.-Regards